# How to I input my mysql database table into this list?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-lists

I'm trying to input my mysql database into this html table without messing up the css, I've tried to do it as shown here with a table, but I can't get it to work.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

The list should look like so..

```
Categories

Business
Computer Science
Economics
English
Engineering
Mathematics
Statistics
Student Success
```

Here is my code,

```
 <div class="col-md-2">  <!-- start left navigation rail column -->
         <div class="panel panel-info spaceabove">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Categories</h4></div>
               <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <?php
                    include "cs234DbConnect.inc.php";
                    $dbc =  mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWD, DBNAME);
                    $error = mysqli_connect_error();
                    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                        echo "Failed to connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }
                    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT CategoryName FROM site7_categories") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
                    while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "<li>" . $result['CategoryName'] . "</li>";
                    }
                    ?>

            </ul>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$list['CategoryName']` instead of `$result['CategoryName']`.

```
while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<li>" . $list['CategoryName'] . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, simple mistake, how would I give each of those a dummy link if you don't mind? Thank you for pointing that out by the way.